# Multivariate Polynomial Division

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Is this train of logic correct? Is there an elementary algebra result that implies what I'm trying to show?

Suppose $f,g$ and $h$ are $\textbf{multivariable}$ polynomials where $q$ is an irreducible polynomial that divides $h$. Then $p=fg+h$ being divisible by $q$ implies that $q$ divides $f$ or $g$.

This can be shown by setting $h=qr$ (here $r$ is another polynomial) and hence

$$
\frac{p}{q}=r+\frac{fg}{q}.
$$

Since $\frac{p}{q}$ is a polynomial so must $\frac{fg}{q}$, proving the conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q$ divides $p=fg+h$ and $q$ divides $h$, then $q$ divides $p-h=fg$.
Since $q$ is a prime element, it divides (by definition) a factor, $f$ or $g$.

Comment: Ah thank you, it's just the definition of a prime element.

Comment: @MR_Q Note that this answer implicitly presumes that irreducibles are prime, which is true in UFDs, but may fail in more general rings.